# Binding using data-win-bind to backgroundImageUrl

Tags: data-binding, winjs

I'm trying to bind the `background-img: url('')` property in a WinJS application.

I've got a view model property which is set to something dynamic like:

```
'images/' + myObject.name + '.jpg'
```

But I'm unsure how to use `data-win-bind` to set said property to the css property `background-img: url('');` correctly.

My template is currently set like this:

```
<div class="item" data-win-bind="style.backgroundImage: backgroundImageUrl">
```

Where `backgroundImageUrl` is my view model property, but this does not seem to setting things correctly.

Any ideas as to how to bind to these properties?

Answer (score 0):

Your data-win-bind syntax looks correct. So there could be two possibilities.

First, make sure you've called WinJS.Binding.processAll. That's necessary to set the binding context and set up the bindings described by data-win-bind attributes. Nothing happens without it.

Second, the value of the source's backgroundImageUrl must be a string in the form that CSS expects, that is, "url('')". It can't just be the relative path itself, like you would use with an img.src target.

To do this, either make the source's property in that form, or use a binding initializer/converter to add the url('') part automatically. For more on that, I suggest looking at Chapter 6 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), with the general data-binding discussion starting on page 299 and the initializer stuff starting on page 315.